# How to do some operation on Large File without storing them in Application Memory

Tags: c#

In a WebApplication deployed on Server when i am doing

```
using(Package pack = Package.Open(FileName.vsdx, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
```

How memory is going to be allocated, Where this **Using** statement will store this data.
What will happen If my file is of around 800 MB,Is it still going to reside in Application memory. if YES then is there any way i can do it in a better way so that It can be mapped to some other Memory location other than Application memory.

Because simultaneously the application is going to be accessed by 300-400 users.

Comment: @varocarbas I'm guessing the OP is using the [`System.IO.Packaging.Package`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.package(v=vs.110).aspx) class for opening a zip file.

Comment: The `using` statement is just making sure that the given object is properly disposed (e.g., calling `pack.Dispose()`). I don't have any experience in what you seem to be using (as suggested by @juharr), but it almost certainly follows the same rules than the remaining `System.IO` classes (otherwise, their creators would have done a really bad job on different fronts). For example: with `StreamReader`, you are only storing the whole file in memory when doing something like `StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path); sr.ReadToEnd();`. That is: reading all its contents, not just opening it.

Comment: It looks like you have to get a `PackagePart` using `GetPart` then you can get a `Stream` using `GetStream`.  That would seem to then give you the ability to load part of the file.  It's likely that `Package.Open` does read in some information from the file, but very unlikely that it would read in the entire file.  To verify that you can write a simple test app and watch the memory usage.

Comment: I can read content from my Package and even i am able to Make desire changes. My concern is with Memory.Suppose the file is of 500MB, then where its gonna reside. Is there any way that i can Map that memory to be stored at some other location, rather than application memory.